# When sending a push notification to multiple Android devices how can I detect which specific device(s) have had the app uninstalled?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) allows the sending of a push notification to multiple devices in a single request.  In the event that a user has uninstalled the app I receive a NotRegistered error response.  How can I tell *which* of the multiple devices has had the app removed (and thereby unregister them and not send them any more notifications)?

Should I play safe and simply send one message per device (treating the multiple device-option as an all-user broadcast) or do alternatives exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending push notifications to more than one device (`registration_ids`) in a single request then your best bet is to use the JSON interface as opposed to the plain-text interface.  The JSON interface will respond with an object showing the number of successes and failures along with a list of `results` objects for each device you sent a push notification to.

Unfortunately, the example in the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html shows an incorrect format.

Here is an example response:

```
{
  "multicast_id":123456,
  "success":1,
  "failure":1,
  "canonical_ids":0,
  "results":[
    {"message_id":"0:abcde"},
    {"error":"NotRegistered"}
  ]
}
```

You can first check the number of `failure`s and, if there failures, iterate through the list of `results`.  The number of elements in `results` will be the same as the number of push messages you sent and the order is the same as the `registation_ids` specified in the request.  You can now find the errors and tally which devices are `NotRegistered` or are even an `InvalidRegistration`; both meaning that the registation_id is no longer valid and your server should stop sending it push notifications.